# Is it possible to refer to environment variables in html file? if so how can I do that?

Tags: html

Is it possible to refer to environment variables in html file? If so how can I do that?

Suppose I have an environment variable VERSION=1.1 and I want to include that in my html file, how can I do it?

Comment: Environment variable from where? Your server? Do you have a server processor like PHP?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained it a bit better, my variable is defined in a prop.txt file and I set the environment variable based on this variable but yes I want/should refer the variable (defined in prop.txt file) in HTML.

Comment: What are the tools you have ? web server, php?

Comment: I don't have a webserver or PHP. I open my .htm file in web browser (firefox). It's a simple file has some text in it and contains version numbers. I don't want to hardcode the version no. so I want it to pick the version number from prop.txt file.

Comment: Not possible unless you do some DOS `type page.html > page1.html; echo %VERSION% >> page1.html`

Answer (score 0):

If you were to find a way of doing it would it not just report the value of the environment variable on the client machine?  most likely 0 ?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained it a bit better, my variable is defined in a prop.txt file and I set the environment variable based on this variable but yes I want/should refer the variable (defined in prop.txt file) in HTML.